# Broacast from webcam to rtmp server

Tags: angular, laravel

I want to broadcast my webcam stream from browser to an **rtmp server**,i tried with **OBS** and its working fine also with **FFMPEG** , but i want to do this in my website.

Comment: Is this a question about code?

Comment: Yes any ideas how can i do this ?

Comment: I’d usually use google for stuff like this..? StackOverflow is meant for solving issues you have already tried to implement I’m afraid. Try some code, and if you get stuck, post your code here and we’ll try to help.

Comment: i tried with google i couldnt find solution. and that is issue for me